# Is there any way to install nodejs/npm in wsl ubuntu via bash script?

Tags: node.js, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So i'm making a bash script to setup my Ubuntu distro in wsl2. I'm trying to install npm so i follow the Microsoft tutorial installing nvm -> then npm with nvm install --lts.
The thing is i can't find a way to install through nvm because nvm installs but then when i run `nvm install --lts` it doesn't work. Now microsoft says i have to reboot the terminal and it does work that way but i wonder if i can do it via the bash script, basically reloding the shell or opening a new one to install npm?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would actually go ahead and look for an NPM that suites your needs with SSH. I then would automate the process with both an initial setup>wait with setTimeouts/intervals till server is back online and continue setup and when server is fully ready it will then begin to respond the way you need it to. No examples unfortunately but hope this helps. :)

Comment: For my setup that may deploy 20-1,000 servers, I require just one "bot" to run this sequence for me and prepare servers. Consider this a premium server bot, that ensures setup goes to plan any errors it's sorted then or later. Any questions just ask but I usually will look at an API of my cloud-provider and use SSH to make this all happen! :)